# Cannot use onItemSelectListener() with Spinner with One Item

Tags: android, focus, spinner

So I have a spinner (spinner2 here) which is populated via an ArrayAdapter from an SQLite table. On selecting an item I want it

- deleted from the DB
- deleted from the spinner

The code below actually works. Except when the spinner has only one item. When that happens
it seems onItemSelected is not called at all.

I get the following LogCat

```
10-01 22:30:55.895: WARN/InputManagerService(1143): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@45a06028
```

Oh and when two items are populating the spinner, spinner.getcount() shows two items, so it's not some strange case of the system thinking the spinner is empty or something like that.

This is the code:

```
public class SpinnerItemSelectListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            if(parent == spinner2){
                if(autoselected){
                    autoselected=false;
                }
                else{
                    //uniqvalarray is the arraymade from pulling data from SQLite and populaitng array adapter
                    Integer i = uniquevalarray.get(pos);
                    deleteRow(i);//deletes the row from the database and repopulates the above array.
                    autoselected=true;//just a boolean to stop autoslecting in onCreate()
                    //makeAlert(i);initially wanted to make alert box.
                    loadSpinner2();//reloads the spinner with new data


                }

            }



        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            //TODO
        }
    }
```

Comment: When that happens it "seems" onItemSelected is not called at all.  ... Seems or it's not really firing?

Comment: Well I put a Log.v("ITEM INFO", pos+" "+spinner2.getCount()+"  "+autoselected); in the method. With two or more items I get the Log result no problem. With one item (and zero - if the DB starts with no data to begin with) I just get the aforementioned WARNING only.

Comment: Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250529/catching-spinner-item-click-when-there-is-only-one-item-listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spinner runs this way : Only fire when you change the selected item . If you dont change that element , cause its the only one that exist , it can't change .

**The solution i think you must use is using a button next to the spinner to throw the delete funcions.**

You must think that Spinner is not made to be with an unique element , cause only changes usually when you change the selected one . then the natural solution can be that .