# Catching spinner item click when there is only one item listed

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to do something which wasn't the spinner specially made for. I got list that changes dynamically. I need to catch onSelectedItemClick when the user choses the item. Problem occurs when there is only one item in the spinner adapter. Selecting it (or rather reselecting, since it was selected already) won't fire OnSelectedItemListener.

How could I catch it otherwise?

Comment: I would suggest add "select" default value, that way you can enforce user to select value other than default (if this approach is OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have only one item then no need to choose from spinner and you can get in `onSeletedItem method.`

- If you have only one item, then onItemSelected is also called.

`String str = (String)parent.getSeletedItem();`